# How to remove columns based on names in a list

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as follows where the top is the column name and each column only has one value:

```
     Sample122       df122      gd412     AKM     532      d21h_7
         32            4           12       25      2         55
```

I also have a dataframe as follows

```
       ID             CN
    Sample22          2
     AKM              1
     532              0
```

I would like to remove the columns in the dataframe based on the list I have. How can I do this?

Comment: `df1[, !names(df1) %in% df2$ID ]`?

Comment: Or use `setdiff` ie. `df1[setdiff(names(df1),df2$ID)]`

Comment: Thanks akrun. Can you add as an answer so I can upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
df1[setdiff(names(df1),df2$ID)]
```